# Triangular inequality in vehicular routing

Tags: optimization, routes, mathematical-optimization

In a literature regarding vehicle routing problem the authors have assumed that triangular inequality is satisfied in the cost matrices. I was wondering is it the common practice to have this assumption in vehicle routing problem or not?

Comment: I think this question would be better dealt with on https://www.or-exchange.org

Comment: You can achieve this in pre-processing the distance matrix. I believe this is often a good idea as the shortest routes delivered by mapping services do not always obey the triangular inequality.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks a lot for your comment. I am not familiar with this type of problem. Can you please provide me some reference on the pre-processing?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about a reference. This is not a very complicated operation however.